# How to slide modal windows from left and right of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wish to have two modal windows hidden, and toggle them to slide in from the left, and another to slide in from the right.
In the fiddle I have created, the left, and right, modal windows align correctly to the left and right of the page, however. The left modal slides in from right instead of sliding "out" from the left margin.
[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/BigKev/vyhpz0d7/1/)

When I try to have the left modal window slide from the left, I lose the slide-out effect.

```css
#rightModal .modal-dialog-slideout {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

#rightModal .modal.fade .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout {
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0)scale(1);
  transform: translate(100%, 0)scale(1);
}

#rightModal .modal.fade.show .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}

#rightModal .modal.fade.show .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#rightModal .modal-dialog-slideout .modal-content {
  border: 0;
}

#rightModal .modal-dialog-slideout .modal-header,
.modal-dialog-slideout .modal-footer {
  height: 69px;
  display: block;
}

#rightModal .modal-dialog-slideout .modal-header h5 {
  float: left;
  color: blue;
}

#leftModal .modal-dialog-slideout {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  background: #fff;
}

#leftModal .modal.fade .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0)scale(1);
  transform: translate(-100%, 0)scale(1);
}

#leftModal .modal.fade.show .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}

#leftModal .modal.fade.show .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#leftModal .modal-dialog-slideout .modal-content {
  border: 0;
}

#leftModal .modal-dialog-slideout .modal-header,
.modal-dialog-slideout .modal-footer {
  height: 69px;
  display: block;
}

#leftModal .modal-dialog-slideout .modal-header h5 {
  float: left;
  color: red;
}
```

How to maintain the slide-out effect, and maintain positions of the two modals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to translate `.modal-dialog -100%` on the `x-axis` when the modal is not shown.

The modal has `.show` class when it is displayed. Use the `:not()` CSS pseudo-class to select the modal in its hidden state.

> The `:not()` CSS pseudo-class represents elements that do not match a
> list of selectors. Since it prevents specific items from being
> selected, it is known as the negation pseudo-class. -  [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```
#leftModal.modal.fade:not(.show) .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%,0)scale(1);
    transform: translate(-100%,0)scale(1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r25uphq3/

Comment: How can I do it if I use <ng-template> ?