# Overlapping Issue of Bootstrap Modals Content in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am displaying 3 Bootstrap modals in single page in my React App and each one have different design. But when I click on any model it displays me the model-body of the 1st modal because of the JavaScript of Bootstrap. So what should I do??

I once had this same problem in my PHP project so I made a variable and then concatenate it in the id of Bootstrap model, that was inside the while loop and then I increment the variable. But applying that solution to the same problem in react give me errors. So what should I do??

Comment: You need single modal that can handle different content including header and footer. Or multiple modal with unique IDs. you can see how there are handled in the documentation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Modal positions in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460853/multiple-modal-positions-in-bootstrap-4)